# Reporting an absolute increase in a given metric

Tags: terminology

In a research article, what is the best formulation to report an absolute increase for a given metric (e.g. F1-score)?

Examples:

- System X achieved an F1-score 9% *(absolute value)* higher than system Y.
- System X achieved an F1-score 9% higher *in absolute value* than system Y.
- System X achieved an F1-score 9 *points* higher than system Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean:

A score of 87.2 percent is 9% higher than a score of 80 percent, but 7.2 points higher.

I would opt for an unambiguous formulation such as the following:

"System X achieved an F1 Score 87.2, 9% higher than system Y at 80."

This is good general advice, but in terms of an actual F1 score it doesn't apply well, as a percentage rise in F1 score is not a metric with a real meaning. For this exact purpose, I would simply report the actual values of the F1 scores.

Comment: Thanks. I meant in terms of absolute increase (vs. relative increase). "Points" is definitely what I would use in French, but I've seen a bunch of articles written in English talking about percentage increases in terms of absolute values (to mean points), so I was curious to know whether it's best to use "points" or "% increase in absolute", as I was starting to have doubt whether "points" what understood by most readers in the English-speaking community.

Comment: Thanks, [percentage point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point) sounds like a great option.

Comment: In that case, yes, "points" or "percentage points" will effectively communicate a change in the magnitude of a rate. I.e. 80% -> 85% is 5 points. This will be well understood by the large majority of readers in a statistical area.

Comment: (I forgot to mention that the readers are from the machine learning and natural language processing communities)

Comment: Sorry- it will be understood by the majority of English speakers- anyone who works more closely with rates (statisticians, scientists, mathematicians, engineers of any kind) are even less likely than an average English speaker to misunderstand the distinction. Your audience will have no problem with this terminology.